# Export documents to either JSON or CSV

Tags: elasticsearch

I know this might be a basic question, but I believe everybody has to learn from some point.

I am trying hard to learn Elasticsearch and as I was going through the documentation at this page

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_exploring_your_data.html

I learned how to load a JSON data and form an index. But later an question arose in my head, how would I be able to export the whole index that I created (here the bank) to CSV or a JSON. Since I couldn't find a solution in Kibana, I searched Github and came across this python script 'es2csv'.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/es2csv/2.4.11

I installed it, but I can't make an output to a format that it should appear in a CSV file. Please, could you help me understand what should I do and clarify the steps i should take because it is vital for me to learn.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recently posted this script which sounds like it has similar goals to es2csv.py above, but just as a single bash script using jq and json2csv.js.

Here it is as a gist:

https://gist.github.com/nzjess/23cbab0fbb3b1b3a63c30e468119612b

This is how I am scripting our exports of CSV from our ELK stack.  Docs are inline.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the most high level option - it would download all indices from elasticsearch, not just one (from the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/es2csv/2.4.1)).

```
es2csv -q 'host: localhost' -o database.csv
```

or to specify an index, use `-i` and your index name:

```
es2csv -i indexname -q 'host: localhost' -o database.csv
```

A better way might be to use kibana to build visualisations. You can then export the data as `Raw` or `Formatted` using the buttons below the visualisation in kibana.

This might work better especially if you build a data table, as the data will be 'flattened' - rather than nested in a json structure which might not be much use when you convert directly to csv.

[image]